# Where to put condition in JOIN Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my query to display district, but I need to select all data whose district = nagpur

My means in, I want to put where condition in my query. Please suggest me how to implement where condition in below query.

```
SELECT RES.PARTYNAME, RES.DISTRICT, COUNT(RES.CONSTITUENCY) AS VOTESCOUNT 
FROM voter_count RES 
JOIN 
    (SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX(VOTES) AS VOTES 
    FROM voter_count
    GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY) MAXS 
USING (VOTES, CONSTITUENCY) 
GROUP BY PARTYNAME,DISTRICT
```

Comment: after `from` :-) or with `having` after `group by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT RES.PARTYNAME, RES.DISTRICT, COUNT( RES.CONSTITUENCY ) AS VOTESCOUNT 
FROM voter_count RES 
JOIN 
  (SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX(VOTES) AS VOTES 
   FROM voter_count
   GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY) MAXS 
USING (VOTES, CONSTITUENCY)
WHERE RES.DISTRICT = 'nagpur'  
GROUP BY PARTYNAME, DISTRICT
```

Comment: @ashish: Was it helpful ?